# Getting user id in index.html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to be able to get the user id using angular to the index.html page. But I'm not able to using the code below. For some reason I'm able to get username, email and other values but not the _id. Could someone help me out?

```
<a ng-show="main.isLoggedIn" class="page-scroll" href="/mytests/{{ main.getId }}">My tests</a>
```

---

```
    // Check if user is logged in
    if (Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
        // Custom function to retrieve user data
        Auth.getUser().then(function(data) {
            if (data.data.username === undefined) {
                app.isLoggedIn = false; // Variable to deactivate ng-show on index
                Auth.logout();
                app.isLoggedIn = false;
                $location.path('/');
            } else {
                app.isLoggedIn = true; // Variable to activate ng-show on index
                app.username = data.data.username; // Get the user name for use in index
                checkLoginStatus = data.data.username;
                app.useremail = data.data.email; // Get the user e-mail for use in index
                app.test1 = data.data.test1;
                app.getId = data.data._id;
```

Comment: What would `console.log(data.data)` yield? Or a plain `console.log(data)`?

Comment: Try changing href to ng-href

Comment: console.log(data.data) yields only username and email. So i guess i have to add the id to the data object?